# How could one edit the Head tags of the Admin in Radiant CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

Is there a hook avaialable to edit the `head` tag in the Admin section of Radiant?

I was hoping to fix IE9's failure to embed links in FCKeditor by placing this tag in it :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

But it seems like the entire admin section is uneditable and tucked away in the gem. And I'd rather not unpack the entire ordeal just to make this small correction.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace any of the HTML in Radiant ~> 0.9.1, you simply have to place a file in an identical tree in your application, preferably in an extension. And Radiant will automagically use your file over the default.